# Prediction with lda in R : Warning message: 'newdata' had 1600 rows but variables found have 200 rows

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

I am new to R. I am trying to use lda to classify all points in a generated grid. The training set is two point groups randomly generated using `rmvnorm(n,mean,sigma)`. Here is my code :`

```
 # number of samples
n=100;

# parameters: G2
meanG1 = matrix( 
  c(2, 2), # the data elements 
  nrow=1,              # number of rows 
  ncol=2,              # number of columns 
  byrow = TRUE)        # fill matrix by rows 
sigmaG1 = matrix( 
  c(1,0,0,1), # the data elements 
  nrow=2,              # number of rows 
  ncol=2,              # number of columns 
  byrow = TRUE)        # fill matrix by rows 

library(mvtnorm)  

# Generating a matrix G1 with norm distribution 
G1 = rmvnorm(n, meanG1, sigmaG1)
G1[,3]=1

# parameters: G2
meanG2 = matrix( 
  c(0, 0), # the data elements 
  nrow=1,              # number of rows 
  ncol=2,              # number of columns 
  byrow = TRUE)        # fill matrix by rows 
sigmaG2 = matrix( 
  c(1,0.75,0.75,1), # the data elements 
  nrow=2,              # number of rows 
  ncol=2,              # number of columns 
  byrow = TRUE)        # fill matrix by rows 

# # Generating a matrix G2 with norm distribution
G2 = rmvnorm(n, meanG2, sigmaG2)

# adding a column as a label = 1 to G1 matrix 
G1 = cbind(G1, 1 )
# adding a column as a label = 2 to G2 matrix 
G2 = cbind(G2, 2 )    
# Concatenate both matrices
G = rbind(G1,G2)    
# Transforming Matrix into dataFrame
bothGroupsWithLabel <- as.data.frame(G)
# Shuffling data row-wise
bothGroupsWithLabel <- bothGroupsWithLabel[sample(nrow(bothGroupsWithLabel)),]

# plotting the generated matrices
plot(c(G1[,1]),c(G1[,2]),col="red")
points(c(G2[,1]),c(G2[,2]),col="blue")

# Generating a grid
K = 40;
seqx1 = seq(min(G1[,1]),max(G1[,1]),length = K)
seqx2 = seq(min(G1[,2]),max(G1[,2]),length = K)
myGrid = expand.grid(z1=seqx1,z2=seqx2);

plot(myGrid[,1],myGrid[,2])

library(MASS)  

# Creating a model
model.lda = lda(bothGroupsWithLabel[,3] ~bothGroupsWithLabel[,1]+bothGroupsWithLabel[,2] , data = bothGroupsWithLabel);
Ypred = predict(model.lda, newdata=myGrid);
Ypredgrid = Ypred$class
```

Here is a part of my data `bothGroupsWithLabel` 
         `V1         V2     V3
69   2.0683949  0.5779272  1
53   2.1261046  2.0420350  1
118 -1.4502033 -1.4775360  2
148  1.1705251  1.5437296  2
195  0.3100763 -0.2594026  2
40   1.8573633  3.7717020  1`

and 
`myGrid
     z1         z2
1 0.1048024 -0.2034172
2 0.2227540 -0.2034172
3 0.3407055 -0.2034172
4 0.4586571 -0.2034172
5 0.5766086 -0.2034172
6 0.6945602 -0.2034172`

my grid consists of 40*40 points, hence the size of `myGird` data frame is 1600 rows and 2 columns. The data frame `bothGroupsWithLabel` consists of 200 rows and 3 columns, the first two columns are the coordinates of the points and the third column is used for labels. My problem is when I call `predict(model.lda, newdata=myGrid)` I get this warning message:
`Warning message:
'newdata' had 1600 rows but variables found have 200 rows`
what am i missing here? can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way that you generated your model. When using a formula and `data=...` it is better to just use the variable names.  In order for this to work,  you must also make the variable names match in `newdata`.  So, when you create myGrid add the line:

```
names(myGrid) = c("V1", "V2")
```

and then make your last few lines be:

```
model.lda = lda(V3 ~ V1 + V2 , data = bothGroupsWithLabel);
Ypred = predict(model.lda, newdata=myGrid);
Ypredgrid = Ypred$class
```

That should get what you want.